# Discord.js PermissionOverwrites Error: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a channel, with only one single person cappable to see it.

I use permissionOverwrites to give permissions to certain users but Im getting this error:

"TypeError [InvalidType]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role."

I tried to set a user ID hardcoded so I AM sure that Im putting a right ID.

My code works fine if I use a role ID, but I need to use a user ID for all cost.

This is what happened:

[image: 1]

(My code and error)

Thank you in advance for your help. <3

EDIT:

I tried this:

server.members.fetch()
.then(member => console.log(member));
And it prints nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution!

The problem was that the client needs the intent GuildPresence.

GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences